# Vba button to activate sheet

Tags: vba, excel-2010, ribbonx

I am trying to write the callback for a button on the backstage view.

I want to select a certain worksheet and show it to the user. I thought about`sheet("sheetName").activate`. This is selecting the sheet *sheetName*, but Excel stays in backstage view.

My question is how can I actually show the sheet, i.e. make it visible? I need to be able to hide backstage view and go to "document view"...

Regards

Comment: I'm going to hazard a guess that you aren't getting any responses because no one knows what a "backstage view" is.

Comment: This is the view you get when you press the "File" tab on Excel 2010: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee691833.aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add the attribute isDefinitive="true" to the ribbon backstage button xml. It will close the backstage view after the button is clicked and switch back to the main view with the previous tab selected.